# What is meant by aggregate in the eShopOnWeb project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity, aggregate, clean-architecture

I want to implement the clean architecture in my own project, but i am relatively new to all these architectural patterns. I don't really understand what is meant by aggregates and when to use aggregate folders for some of my core entities.

**For example:** The eShopOnWeb project on GitHub (https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb/tree/master/src/ApplicationCore/Entities) has a BasketAggregate, a BuyerAggregate and a OrderAggregate...

I am sure this is a noob question but i found nothing about it on Google...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Aggregate root is an entity that has some other entities which cannot live without this certain aggregate. Let's take a blog website for example. We have some topics/posts and there are also comments.Comments cannot exist without a post that they are related to.

Some resource that can be helpful:
https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html